# how to active first accordion by dfault

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Below is the accordion I have achieved and it looks good now I am trying to assign the first accordion as a default open but I am unable to do. I think i must be done with jquery but I am noob in Js and all. Appreciate your quick solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //toggle the component with class accordion_body
    $(".accordion_head").click(function () {
        if ($('.accordion_body').is(':visible')) {
            $(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
            $(".plusminus").text('+');
        }
        if ($(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
        } else {
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(300);
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.accordion_container {
    width: 100%;
}
.accordion_head {
    background-color:#e74c3c;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Abel';
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    padding: 7px 11px;
    padding-left:35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.accordion_body {
    font-size: 20px!important;
    background: transparent;
    color:#666;
    padding: 7px 11px;
    padding-left:35px;
    padding-right:35px;
}
.accordion_body p {
    padding: 18px 5px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.plusminus {
  font-size: 20px!important;
    float:right;
}


.accordion_container h5{
  font-family: 'Abel';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  color: #666;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion_container">
          <div class="accordion_head"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>Accordion #01<span class="plusminus">+</span>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion_body">
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div><hr>
          <div class="accordion_head"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>Accordion #02<span class="plusminus">+</span>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion_body">
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div><hr>
          <div class="accordion_head"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>Accordion #03<span class="plusminus">+</span>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion_body">
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Just add a `style="display:block;"` to the first `accordion_body` element. And for all the others just do `style="display:none;"`

Comment: This all seems to be easily doable by using Bootstrap. Is there any specific reason you are not doing this with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just trigger the click event on the first one after it is loaded, so your new js would look like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //toggle the component with class accordion_body
    $(".accordion_head").click(function () {
        if ($('.accordion_body').is(':visible')) {
            $(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
            $(".plusminus").text('+');
        }
        if ($(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
        } else {
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(300);
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');
        }
    });

    $(".accordion_head").first().click(); //<-- new line of code
});
```

Comment: That will only collapse all the accordions he has in the `accordion_container`.

Comment: Awesome .. its working just what  I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I have added display: none to the class .accordion_body which will hide the body for each tabs and added a class .active which is added to the html code of first accordion-tab so that its opened by default.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //toggle the component with class accordion_body
    $(".accordion_head").click(function () {
        if ($('.accordion_body').is(':visible')) {
            $(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
            $(".plusminus").text('+');
        }
        if ($(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
        } else {
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(300);
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.accordion_container {
    width: 100%;
}
.accordion_head {
    background-color:#e74c3c;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Abel';
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    padding: 7px 11px;
    padding-left:35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.accordion_body {
    font-size: 20px!important;
    display: none;
    background: transparent;
    color:#666;
    padding: 7px 11px;
    padding-left:35px;
    padding-right:35px;
}
.accordion_body p {
    padding: 18px 5px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.plusminus {
  font-size: 20px!important;
    float:right;
}
.active{
display: block;
}


.accordion_container h5{
  font-family: 'Abel';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  color: #666;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion_container">
          <div class="accordion_head"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>Accordion #01<span class="plusminus">+</span>
          </div>
          <div class="active accordion_body">
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div><hr>
          <div class="accordion_head"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>Accordion #02<span class="plusminus">+</span>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion_body">
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div><hr>
          <div class="accordion_head"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>Accordion #03<span class="plusminus">+</span>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion_body">
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: did u add class .active{
display: block;
} in your css

Comment: yes I added .active in css as well as in html it was a good way to sort it out but I knew it that it must be somewhere within js ...