# Accordion open when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordion where open/closes on click. However I would like the accordion to be open when the page loads. Does anyone know what I need to add/remove from the below code? all suggestions are welcome.

```js
reviewsLink.on('click', function() {
   util.scrollBrowser(feefoCont.offset().top - 97);
   $('.js-feefo-content').delay(500).slideDown();
   if (reviewstitle.text() === originaltitle) {
    reviewstitle.toggleText(Resources.REVIEWS_HIDE, originaltitle);
   }
  });
  reviewsLinkM.bind('click', function() {
   util.scrollBrowser(feefoContM.offset().top);
   $('.js-feefo-toggle.pdp-main__feefo-slot__toggle.js-slot-accordion.pdp-main__slot--accordion').delay(500).slideDown();
   
   feefoContM.find('h3').addClass('pdp-main__tab--icon-minus');
  });


  var reviewsCont = $('.pdp-main__feefo-slot .js-reviews-toggle'),
   reviewsClose = $('.js-feefo-content').find('.js-feefo-close');

  reviewsCont.bind('click', function() {
   $('.js-feefo-content').slideToggle();

   reviewstitle.toggleText(Resources.REVIEWS_HIDE, originaltitle);

  });

  reviewsClose.bind('click', function() {
   $('.js-feefo-content').slideUp();

   reviewstitle.toggleText(Resources.REVIEWS_HIDE, originaltitle);
  });
 }
};
```

Comment: this question seems similar to the question discussed before. please check if it is helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851552/how-to-active-first-accordion-by-dfault/43851866#43851866

Comment: @komal Yes that worked. thumbs up!